# Adding metadata to pdfs in solr from commadn line

Tags: bash, pdf, solr, metadata

I want to add custom metadata to every pdf I index in solr, for instance the company to which it belongs and some links to an external administration app

I managed to ingest the pdfs and make them highlight able with help of the post tool provided

```
ls ~/test_solr/*.pdf | xargs  -I{} bash -c " ./bin/post -c ratingdocs -p 8983 "{}"; sleep 10 "
```

because this is so simple I was wondering if it is at the same time possible to add metadata. Is something like this possible?

```
./bin/post -c ratingdocs -p 8983 doc.pdf -params="company_name=<<company name>>&url=app.com/company/<<company_id>>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can populate arbitrary fields in your documents by prefixing the field name with `literal.`. So your command would become:

`./bin/post -c ratingdocs -p 8983 doc.pdf -params="literal.company_name=<<company name>>&literal.url=app.com/company/<<company_id>>"`

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works perfectly without changing anything in the schema. A side note is that when fetching the fields you do not need the **literal.** prefix